# Unity AI, changes Y position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was creating Unity AI, but suddenly, for no reason, my AI has changed it position to -4 on Y.
I think the navmeshagent causes that, but without it my enemy wont work.
Here's entire script:

```
public float RaycastMax;
public LayerMask PlayerMask;

public GameObject[] PosList;

public NavMeshAgent AI;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,0,transform.position.z);
    RaycastHit hit;
    // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, RaycastMax, PlayerMask))
    {
        //Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
        print("I see");
    } else
    {
        GameObject O = PosList[Random.Range(0, PosList.Length)];
        Vector3 pos = O.transform.position;
        //print(pos);
        //pos.y = 0;

        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pos) <= 0.1f)
        {
            GameObject Object = new GameObject();
            Object.transform.position = pos;
            print(Object.transform.position);

            AI.destination = Object.transform.position;
            print(AI.destination);
            Destroy(Object);
        }
    }    
}
}
```

Also i checked, Object position y is normal (0),but destination of AI says -4 on Y axis

Comment: Just checking, have you made any changes to the navmesh and if so have you re-baked it?

Comment: No i didn't. But i checked (rebaked mesh) and my AI dont work still. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Guys I found out one thing!! When creating for example sphere, and adding navmeshagent, you can see this collider! Thats why ai  changed y pos, but now my AI has stopped working